# Why do I get the same error code when Geocoding?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geocoding, mmqgis

Whenever I use the 'MMQGIS' plug in to 'Geocode' a CSV file containing postcodes to get the longitude and latitude which will enable me to plot the locations as a layer on QGIS, it always come up with the error code seen below.

```
Failure creating output file: Creation of data source failed (OGR error: C:\Users\louis.gorringe\Desktop\Chemical.shp is not a directory.)
```

So although the shapefile may be present after running the geocoding. whenever I exit QGIS versions 3.10.0 and re open it, all shapefiles have dissapered. Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried saving to a different location/file for starters?

Comment: Yes I have, I have tried saving to shared and local drives.

Comment: I have the same issues. Plus: MMQGIS tells me that it is "not responding" while it is actually geocoding. The fix suggested below does not work for me. It might also depend on operating systems?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, what seemed to work is to create an empty directory, and save the .shp file in that, e.g.:

`C:\Users\louis.gorringe\Desktop\Chemical\Chemical.shp`

Also, make sure the `Not Found Output List` is saved to a different directory.